# How can i use a different file and make it used in a other ?? (Python)

Tags: python, encryption, menu

I'am new to python, and im trying to get the user to input their message through a file that will be encrypted or decrypted. I have tried to research on how i could do it but i'am lost to what to do !

Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome! Would you like to encrypt a message or decrypt message ? ")
print("1. encrypt message")
print("2. decrypt message")
print("3. exit programme")
print("Selection 1 or 2 or 3? Please enter your selection:")

while True:
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        print("Please enter your file that you want to be encrypted:")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Please enter your file that you want to be decrypted:")
    else:
        exit
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; as it appears to not be your first language, it may help if you get someone with better English skills to proofread your article before posting.

Comment: Do you want to decrypt/encypt the given file name and do you have any algorithm to encrypt/decrypt

Comment: what is your encrypt and decrypt methods?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want, are you asking for someone to explain how to edit a file with Python or how to do the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like the GCSE AQA computer science Traditional scenario task... funny that.

The way you have started shows that you are new to programming. One of the menu options is to exit the program, and with a while loop if the condition is true it will run. Because you have written true it will never be false. Ergo it runs forever so exiting is not an option.

this is how the menu could work

```
#this could be your menu loop

    def menu():
        print("1] Encrypt text")
        print("2] Decrypt text")
        print("3] exit program")
        choice = input("Choice: ") #There is no point Turing it into an integer, it      just allows for the program to break is someone types anything other than a number
        if choice == "1":
            encryption()
            menu()
        elif choice == "2":
            decryption()
            menu()
        elif choice == "3"
            print("Exiting...")
        else:
            print("Invalid selection")
            menu()
```

The actual en/decryption requires you to get text from a file and then add an offset generated by getting a value from a random key (if this is part of your coursework)

The actual program is way too long to put on here and explain. While statements are really a basic thing to struggle with . Also not knowing how this works makes it impossible to do the written segment which score way more marks.

I am currently doing that GCSE aswell and lots of people are struggling with it because this sort of IT is not taught widely enough which is a shame.